# html5 drag and drop upload broken in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, file-upload

I have been working on this bug for a while now , for some reason the drag and drop uploading I implemented on my site has not been working in chrome.  No error messages or anything.  Just when you try to drag a file over the designated area you get the mouse icon of the circle with the line through it.  So after testing and testing and testing I came to realize that even if I go to the html5 Official demo page for the drag and drop it does not work there either in Google Chrome.

Has anyone ran into this?  is there some type of security setting that got triggered in my Chrome browser that is preventing the drag-n-drop ??  I am concerned now that there may be other user that may run into this.  Currently I check if the user's browser if HTML5 compatable and then only offer the drag-n-drop option, if not I fall back to the choose a file button.  But now I'm learning that there may be a third case - which is mine now .  I have the newest version of Chrome , but it just for some reason started blocking drag-n-drop a few days ago. It used to work just fine.

### EDIT

the  [HTML5 drag-n-drop demo site](http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload)

and I'm using Chrome Version 39.0.2171.65 m

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? Can you also provide a link to the Test page that you're using?

Comment: the link given by you will only support JPEG/GIF/PNG images to upload.
Remove that filteration condition.
[see view-source and condition](http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload#view-source)

Comment: I'm using Chrome 40.0.2214.111 m and the demo page you've linked to is working fine for me. I uploaded quite a large image without any problems

Answer (score 0):

I found strangely enough (on version 57.0.2987.110) that closing all instances of chrome, opening task manager and making sure it is fully closed, then restarting it seemed to get the dropping working again.

I'm not sure of a fix when this is occurring but I did see a bug report about this at https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/RgPdExhVPMs but it looks to me like a browser update (as this was originally posted in 2015 and likely isn't a problem anymore) would fix it right up.